# Replace substrings between tags in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, dom, substring

I have been working on this for whole day but couldn't find a solution in which I can replace substrings in string in php like I have string

```
'<div>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p>Hello World</p>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p>Hello Universe</p>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
</div>'
```

I want to get every string inside h2 and then perform some htmlentity replacement like

```
$str = 'this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag';
$sanitized = htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_QUOTES);
```

and then output complete string but replaced.

How it can be done?

```
<div>
    <h2>this is &lt;span&gt;String&lt;/span&gt; found in h2 tag</h2>
    <p><b>Hello</b> World</p>
    <h3>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h3>
    <p><b>hello</b> Universe</p>
    <h2>this is &lt;span&gt;String&lt;/span&gt; found in h2 tag</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: See if this helps http://us2.php.net/book.dom

Comment: cannot there be some simple solution to get substring and perform some calculations and then replace? This seems I will have to rework alot. And truth is that I have become dumb now as I have already invested my whole day on it

Comment: I would point you to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags.

Comment: While it might seem simpler to use substr, dom is definitely the right solution. Embrace the lost day as a learning experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Regular expression for matching `<h2>` tags is :

```
/<h2>(.+?)<\/h2>/
```

If you would like to match all `<hx>`tags instead use the following instead:

```
/<h([1-6])(.*?)<\/h\1>/
```

In callback function you can alter the matched string. For example:

```
$html = <<< EOH

<div>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p>Hello World</p>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p>Hello Universe</p>
   <h2>this is <span>String</span> found in h2 tag</h2>
</div>

EOH;

$html = preg_replace_callback("/<h2>(.+?)<\/h2>/", function($matches) {
    /* Convert content of <h2> tags to HTML entities. */
    $altered =  htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_QUOTES);

    /* Put the converted content back inside <h2> tag and return it. */
    return str_replace($matches[1], $altered, $matches[0]);
}, $html);

$html = preg_replace_callback("/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/", function($matches) {
    /* Make match bold. */
    $altered = "<b>" . $matches[1] . "</b>";

    /* Put the converted content back inside <p> tag and return it. */
    return str_replace($matches[1], $altered, $matches[0]);
}, $html);

print $html;
```

Output of the above script is:

```
<div>
   <h2>this is &lt;span&gt;String&lt;/span&gt; found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p><b>Hello World</b></p>
   <h2>this is &lt;span&gt;String&lt;/span&gt; found in h2 tag</h2>
   <p><b>Hello Universe</b></p>
   <h2>this is &lt;span&gt;String&lt;/span&gt; found in h2 tag</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW Mika this is just awesome man. Can I replace <p> content as well altogether with <h2> to change Hello in <p> as well? I am editing my question, please see if it possible

Comment: I want to make bold all of <p> tags as well beside replacing h2 contents. Is it possible to do it in same function you said?

Comment: Updated the example to match additional question. If it answers the question mark it approved.

Comment: Thanks Mika. Isn't it possible to do both of bold and htmlreplacement in one single function?

Comment: You can pass array of regexps to  preg_replace_callback() so it could be done. Problem is you need to also know which regexp watch matched since you are doing different transformations on them.

Comment: Thank Mika I already did as you said but now there is a strange problem that if a string is given which consists on 2 or more lines it fails to parse that. Something like this it is ok with <p>abc</p> but fails on <p>ab //Line break c</p>

Comment: Mika I have posted a question plz see if it is solvable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810777/php-regex-preg-replace-callback-fails-to-handle-mutliple-lines