# php regex preg_replace_callback fails to handle mutliple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have a code like

```
 $newstr = preg_replace_callback("/<p>(.+?)</p>/", function($matches) 
 {
    return str_replace($matches[1], '<b>' . $matches[1] . '</b>', $matches[0]);
 }, $str);
```

It replaces if a single line string is given like this

```
 '<p>Hello World and Hello Universe</p>'
```

but fails when multiple lines are given like

```
  '<p>Hello World and
         Hello Universe</p>'
```

How it can be handled? If for test purpose I give string like this

```
  '<p>Hello World and'.
         'Hello Universe</p>'
```

It works but the problem is this string is coming from a textarea and cannot understand what to do?

Comment: use the s modifier to allow multiline statements

Comment: Thanks @Tularis Amal suggested that.

Comment: I know, posted this at the same time as amal did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (also called `DOTALL` modifier). The dot metacharacter, by default, matches everything except newlines. The `s` modifier makes it match newlines as well:

```
$newstr = preg_replace_callback("~<p>(.+?)</p>~s", function($matches) {
    return str_replace($matches[1], '<b>' . $matches[1] . '</b>', $matches[0]);
}, $str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102131)

Comment: Thanks Amal it worked. I am really weak at Regex it was suggested by Mika a great one.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Glad I could help. I suggest going through http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - It's a great resource for learning regex :)

Comment: Thanks for the link I will see that and will accept answer after 10 minutes as required by SO